# How to make gv (DOT) files work under LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx

I'm using LyX. After adding [this gv file](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.gv.txt) using Insert->Graphics, LyX automatically generated a perfect preview of the file, as expected.
[image: Automatic preview of GraphViz in LyX]
However, when I try to export or get a preview using dvi (Ctrl+D) or pdflatex (Ctrl+R), I get the following LaTeX error:

> Package pdftex.def Error: File `1_home_user_Documents_PATH_TO_FOLDER_fsm.png' not found.

and the following LyX error (message box):

> No information for converting  format files to png. Define a converter in the preferences.

Background info:

1. After installing GraphViz I did Tools->Reconfigure.
2. The GraphViz Dot -> PNG converter is defined as `dot -Tpng $$i -o $$o`.
3. Converting the gv file manually to png doesn't help (unless of course if I use the png file directly as the graphics...).

Answer (score 2):

Use `dot -Tsvg foo.dot > foo.svg` to export your graph in vector format, then embed that.

Comment: I'm not sure why LyX would choose to export the graph to PNG format to begin with...

Comment: Please add a little more detail (including accompanying theoretical knowledge) to improve the answer.

Comment: @badp a probably reason for why LyX would export the graph to PNG is because no one has reported this bug. Please help us fix it by reporting it with a minimal example at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @badp, if I understand correctly, your suggestion is manual convertion to a different format. Is there a way to avoid this? i.e. if LyX is doing fine with generating a preview, the export to PDF should work as well...

Comment: @scottkosty On my Ubuntu system, LyX seems to embed a .dot file in vector format (EPS, perhaps?). I'm not entirely sure I'm the right person to file this bug report.

Comment: @badp Ah so you are not seeing that issue, it is the OP. I see now. Thanks for getting back to me on it.